# What is not inverted when a string wave reflects with phase reversal?

Tags: waves, reflection, string, boundary-conditions

When a wave reaches a boundary and it is reflected, it may happen that, if certain conditions are fulfilled, there is a phase reversal (180$^\circ$), so that what came as a crest becomes a trough and vice versa.

It is, however, said that, if we talk about a sound wave, what is inverted is the pressure, not the displacement and, if the wave is an electromagnetic one, the electric field is reversed, not the magnetic field.

What about a string wave? I think that the same approach should be valid, but I cannot find the words about what is reversed and what remains unaltered.

Is the following maybe the right approach for finding the answer? The two things that are at stake, as reversable or not, are akin to the components of both impedance and wave speed, i.e. rigidity and inertia. Thus what is reversed in the sound and in the EM case would be the rigidity element (represented by pressure and electric field, respectively), leaving unaltered the inertia (displacement and magnetic field, respectively) . In the string case, could we say that what is reversed is, instead, the sense of displacement in the Y direction (akin to inertia?), leaving tension (rigidity) untouched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I think the answer is quite clear. Suprisingly, the parallelism is great between string and sound waves.

In the case of sound, when the phase of the pressure wave (i.e. difference over ambient pressure, which is 0, or alternatively the wave of the particle's velocity around mean position in X axis) is reversed, what is not reversed is the wave of particle's displacement in X (or alternatively of the difference between pressure from each side).

In the case of the string, when the phase of the tension wave (i.e. difference over the string's "ambient" perpendicular tension, which is 0, or alternatively the wave of the particle's velocity around mean position in Y axis) is reversed, what is not reversed is the wave of particle's displacement in Y (or alternatively of the difference in perpendicular upward and downward tension).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why do you ask this question and what exactly you are asking but here's my best effort.

The solutions to these reflections are found by imposing boundary conditions on the wave equations. Imagine a horizontal string and wave propagating to the right on it, which reflects off of a point. You can model all possible waves by a combination of sin and cos functions.

$y_{incoming}(x,t) = Asin(x-vt) + Bcos(x-vt)$

$y_{reflected}(x,t) = Csin(x+vt) + Dcos(x+vt)$

(Change from -vt to +vt reflects the change in direction, and constants A, B, C, D determine the ratios of these terms to one another)

If we say that the string is glued to a point at x = 0, we will get the inversion you talked about. For this to be true, y(0,t) should be 0 at all times. So when you try to come up with an equation for the reflecting wave, you have to impose $y(0,t) = y_{incoming}(0,t) + y_{reflected}(0,t) = 0$ So that the string doesn't move at the connection point x=0.

$y_{incoming}(0,t) = Asin(-vt) + Bcos(-vt)$

$y_{reflected}(0,t) = Csin(-vt) + Dcos(-vt)$

$y(0,t) = (A+C)sin(-vt) + (B+D)cos(-vt)$

Only if C = -A and D = -B, this formula will give 0 for all t values. Basically for any wave solution f(x-vt), the ideal reflection will be -f(x+vt).

For any kind of wave there is, there will be some value that propagates in time and space, pressure, displacement, electric field etc. So, they all can be modeled as "value = f(x-vt)". And when you impose that there is a point $x = x_0$, where the value is always 0, you'll see a similar result for all these kinds of waves.

As you may have realized, I have talked about what got inverted but not about what didn't. That's because there is no need. Waves are basically disturbances of some value that will propagate in a medium as time passes. For example, the displacement for a sound wave which stayed untouched in your example was completely irrelevant in the first place. Sound is not about the displacement of the molecules which mostly stays stationary, it only involves pressure. The vertical displacement was the only value we kept track in our example so everything else stayed untouched, because they weren't involved in the process in the first place.

You may now say that this arguments completely gets crushed once we think about electromagnetic waves. But what's different about the electromagnetic waves is the boundary conditions you have to impose. Charges in a conductor will move around such that it has 0 net electric field on it (since any other configuration will cause the charges to move and therefore not a stable configuration). This means a conductor creates a boundary condition like our previous example. But the magnetic field has no such requirement and acts more like a freely connected string, which as you probably know will cause a reflection but not an inversion.

Comment: Thanks, your comments are very helpful. What I don't understand is that, on the one hand, you accept that a wave can be modeled as how a value (one of the different values involved in wave motion) changes over time or space, but on the other hand you seem to dismiss the modeling of sound based on displacement. Well, it may not be so obvious or graphical, but it has always been accepted as a possible approach, just as the typical one in the case of a string is the modeling based on Y displacement, but another based on tension could also be adopted...

Comment: Another thing that I don't understand is that your equation of the wave function is the sum of two terms, precisely separated by pi/2. Isn't this like the superposition of the two wave models, as if you added up the displacement and the pressure waves of sound?

Comment: @Sierra the reason I used two functions precisely separated pi/2 is because they can be linearly combined to create any waveform possible. They are not representing two different aspects of a wave, they are representing the oscillations of the same value, displacement at (x,t). I didn't want to clutter the argument but the more general approach would be to use many sin/cos functions all with different frequencies to create any wave possible. You do this by multiplying the input with various wave numbers shown as k (sin(k(x-vt)). Check Fourier transform for more details.

Comment: @Sierra The thing is, you keep falling into the same trap. Just because there can both be oscillations of y displacement and oscillations of tension on a string, you can't deduce they are the part of the same process. Even if they are always observed simultaneously. The wave of tension and the wave of displacement aren't the part of the same phenomenon, one is a transverse wave and the other is a longitudinal one. The fact that they can coexist and even that they usually do so doesn't prove otherwise.

Comment: Well, the fact that a sound wave can be modeled by plotting the change of amplitude in either X Displacement or Pressure over time does not seem objectable. A similar thing should be possible with a wave string. But I have discarded Tension since I am concluding that it is not that it oscillates in phase with Y displacement, it is even that it is assumed NOT to oscillate because the change in tension of the string is deemed neglectable to avoid non-linear effects. My candidate value, to accompany Y Displacement, is now Y Velocity.

Comment: Nope, not velocity. In the end I think that I've found the winner: the difference between tension from each side of the string as given by the slope of the curve, which actually has pi/2 difference with Y displacement: the slope is max at y = 0 and 0 at y = max. I would not say that this is an abnormal value to model a string wave with, since we are talking about its very restoring force.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. On trying to better understand how tension and even velocity of the elements in Y axis evolve over time, nothing is clear to me... Maybe I should ask that peliminary question.

Answer (score 0):

> if we talk about a sound wave, what is inverted is the pressure, not the displacement

Not true. Either one can be inverted depending on what causes the reflection. The easiest example here is a pipe: at an open end, the pressure will be inverted but the particle velocity stays the same. At a closed end it's the other way around. The pressure stays the same and the particle velocity inverts.

> if certain conditions are fulfilled, there is a phase reversal (180∘),

That's exactly what this is about. There is a phase reversal occurs when the right conditions are met regardless of whether it's sound, EM or mechanical. So the reflection phase of a string depends on how it's terminated and what causes the reflection.

Comment: Your way of describing the issue (“either value can be inverted depending on what causes the reflection”) is not the conventional one. I did not use it in order not to complicate the discussion. But it’s legitimate and I can perfectly but it. The thing is however that you do not answer the question under your own approach. For this you would have to fill in the gaps here: “in the string example, at a fixed end the [A] will be inverted but the [B] stays the same; at a free end it's the other way around, i.e. the [B] is inverted and the [A] stays the same”.

Comment: Displacement of a string flips phase at a fixed end and maintains phase at an open end, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: If we fill in the gaps in my question this means that “in the string example, at a fixed end the phase of Displacement will be inverted but the phase of [B] stays the same; at a free end it's the other way around, i.e. the phase of [B] is inverted and the phase of Displacement stays the same”. The missing gap in your text is still [B], but I gather that the answer is the one anticipated in my Question, it is obviously Tension.

Comment: Or not... I am thinking that I am seeking two values whose phases are separated by pi/2. With sound that may be Displacement vs Pressure, but with the string max Displacement in Y would be max Tension as well...  Maybe for a string I need Displacement in Y (or Tension) vs Velocity also in Y.

Comment: Correction: as I told Gundogan, it appears that Tension is not even a candidate value, as it is assumed not to oscillate during the wave's motion, because the change in length and consequently tension due to the disturbance is deemed neglectable, which is good because otherwise the thing would go non-linear.

Comment: Later I came back to Tension (assuming that Tension on the string is fixed but the disturbance precisely creates an unbalance between the transverse components), but then I thought that this seems to lead to values in line with Y displacement, so it is clear that I must better grasp the intricacies of the string wave before continuing the discussion.